# Vue3 issue calling getter method in another getter method within the same Pinia store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

Currently working in Vue3 using Typescript, Vuetify, and the Composition API. I am also defining stores using Pinia.

I am trying to call a getter method in another getter method, both of which are within the same store, but I'm getting a series of errors and everything I've found so far seems to cause more/other errors.

This is an example of what I'm working with:

```
// ... imports

export const useExampleStore = defineStore('example-store', {
  state: () =>
    ({
      report: { ...initialReport },
      groups: { ...initialGroups },
    } as ExStoreState),
  getters: {
    exMethodOne(state) { // <----------- having issues with calling this method
      if (state.report.type != 'code' || !state.report.forceAdmin) {
        return formatParams(state.groups.selections);
      } else {
        return state.report.selection_codes;
      }
    },
    exMethodTwo(state, getters) { // <---------- issues calling exMethodOne in this
      const selectionCodes = getters.exMethodOne() // <---------- issue occurs here
      return {
        'filters[selection_codes][]': selectionCodes,
        // ... additional hash items, similar to that above
      } as any;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    // ... action methods
  },
});
```

Initially, I thought I'd be able to just call `exMethodOne` in `exMethodTwo` after defining it, ex: `const selectionCodes = exMethodOne()` , but that gives a `Cannot find name 'exMethodOne'` error.

After that didn't work, I took to the internet and everything I've seen tells me to add `getters` to the arguments for `exMethodTwo` like you see in the example above, then call `exMethodOne` like so:

```
exMethodTwo(state, getters) {
      const selectionCodes = getters.exMethodOne()
// ... etc. etc.
```

When I add this `getters` argument though, I got this set of errors from Vue:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(id: "statements-report", options: Omit<DefineStoreOptions<"statements-report", SrsState, _GettersTree<SrsState>, { getLabelGroups(report: ReportType): Promise<...>; SongSearch(): Promise<...>; getUserStatemntsReport(values: StatementReportParams): Promise<...>; getStatement(values: StatementDownloadParams): Promise<...>; getAdminStatemntsReport(values: StatementReportParams): Promise<...>; }>, "id">): StoreDefinition<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(state: any, getters: any) => any' is not assignable to type '(() => any) | ((state: SrsState & PiniaCustomStateProperties<SrsState>) => any)'.
      Type '(state: any, getters: any) => any' is not assignable to type '() => any'.
        Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 0.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(id: "statements-report", storeSetup: () => unknown, options?: DefineSetupStoreOptions<"statements-report", _UnwrapAll<Pick<unknown, never>>, Pick<unknown, never>, Pick<unknown, never>> | undefined): StoreDefinition<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ state: () => SrsState; getters: { accountNumber: () => string; resetReport(state: SrsState & PiniaCustomStateProperties<SrsState>): void; configureSongCodes(state: SrsState & PiniaCustomStateProperties<...>): any; filterSetter(state: any, getters: any): any; }; actions: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => unknown'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type '() => unknown'.
```

The errors go away if I remove the `getters` argument, but it just brings me back to the `Cannot find name 'exMethodOne'` error.

How can I call my `exMethodOne` from within my `exMethodTwo` considering they're both in the same Pinia store?

Comment: What did make you think that there's second param in a getter? `state` includes both state data and getters. The whole store is consistently available as `this`

Comment: @EstusFlask Unfortunately, using `this` didn't work for me either. Pretty much just replaced `getters.exMethodOne()` with `this.exMethodOne()` and I get this error back: 

`Property 'exMethodOne' does not exist on type 'ExStoreState & _StoreWithGetters<{}> & PiniaCustomProperties<string, StateTree, _GettersTree<StateTree>, _ActionsTree>'.`

Spinning up localhost, I'm getting errors saying `exMethodOne` cannot be read.

Comment: The error is in console? There could be multiple causes for type problems. There should be one param, i.e. exMethodTwo(state) and not exMethodTwo(state, getters), otherwise it may not be recognized as a getter. A getter is not a function, it's incorrect to use it as exMethodOne(). Try `this.exMethodOne` and `state.exMethodOne`